# DataTables warning: table id=clientstable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

Hi I am getting this error

DataTables warning: table id=clientstable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

and when I inspect the page then get this

[Please check the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ftA1.png)

its jquery error..

I dont know how to solve the issue..

please help

I try to hide the code
//'serverSide': true,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#clientstable').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            //'serverSide': true,
            'stateSave': true,
            'order': [],
            'ajax': {
                'url': "<?php echo site_url('filling/rload_list?status='.$status)?>",
                'type': 'POST'
            },
            'columnDefs': [
                {
                    'targets': [0],
                    'orderable': false,
                },
            ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

and also tried exit();

```
$output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->request->count_all($employee, $status, $this->aauth->get_user()->roleid ),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->request->count_filtered($employee, $status, $this->aauth->get_user()->roleid ),
            "data" => $data,
        );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
        exit();
```

But still the same issue is there..

Comment: What is the exact error message from the 500 status? You will need to click on the name of the request to reveal the error message in the response tab.